# Selecting 2 tables from 2 different databases (ACCESS)

Tags: ms-access, select, ado, union

here is the connection i have

```
strCon="DBQ=" & Server.Mappath("db.mdb") & ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};PWD=password;"
set adoCon=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
adoCon.Open strCon
```

so in order to work with the 2 databases i have 2 adoCon and when i do the select i select from each db i need

now for the problem...
in this situation i will be able only to get all the info from one and then from the other one. but what i want is to be able to put the together.

db1.tblcats has categories and db2.tblcats has categories and subcategories
so in addition to be able to select both of the together, i need to be able to know what cat is from what db

---

Step 2 after the big help

this is my code

```
strSQL = "SELECT name FROM tblcats union " _ 
& "select name from [MS Access;PWD=pass;DATABASE=" & Server.Mappath("../shop.mdb") & "].tblcats as bcats where bcats.father=50"
                                rs.CursorType = 3
                                rs.LockType = 3
                                rs.Open strSQL, strCon
while not rs.eof
response.write rs("name")&"<br>"
rs.movenext
wend
```

how can i know what record came from what db? cause i need to act difrently for each one

Comment: What's your programming environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IN:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM atable 
IN 'C:\Docs\DB2.mdb') t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

EDIT:

```
sc = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\docs\other.mdb"
cn.open sc

s="SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN " _
& "[MS Access;PWD=databasePWD;DATABASE=C:\docs\db.mdb].t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID"

rs.Open s, cn
```

EDIT 2:

You can use the aliases to identify which database a field is from:

```
s="SELECT * FROM table1 t INNER JOIN " _
& "[MS Access;PWD=databasePWD;DATABASE=C:\docs\db.mdb].m ON t.ID=m.ID"

 msgbox rs.fields("m.code") & " " & rs.fields("t.code")
```

EDIT 3

Or you can add a virtual field:

```
 SELECT 1 AS "DB", Field, Field FROM  ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 AS "DB", Field, Field FROM
```

UNION ALL is usually faster.

Comment: not working...
I'm getting: "Syntax error in FROM clause"
be aware that both of the DB has password and that they are not in the same folder

Comment: ok... i have edited the question - please continue with your help :-)

Comment: look closly as i'm not using inner join but union.
how can i add a new column that will have a number for each recod (1 if from local and 2 if from remote)?