# Excel VBA - how to query Access database using column values as a parameter?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that has a list of about 1000 Item Numbers in column A on Sheet1. Currently, I import Sheet1 into an Access table named `ItemNumbers` and run the following query:

```
SELECT MyTable.ItemNumber, MyTable.ItemName, MyTable.ItemPrice
FROM [ItemNumbers] INNER JOIN MyTable ON [ItemNumbers].ItemNumber = MyTable.ItemNumber
ORDER BY MyTable.ItemNumber;
```

And then I copy/paste the output to Sheet2.

How can I do this in VBA in Excel and put the results in a recordset? I can figure out how to loop through the recordset and put the results in Sheet2. I'm just not sure on the code to run the query.

I have the following so far. It just needs to be modified to use the values in Sheet1 Column A.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\MyDatabase.accdb"
strSql = "SELECT MyTable.ItemNumber, MyTable.ItemName, MyTable.ItemPrice " & _
         "FROM MyTable " & _
         "WHERE WHERE (((MyTable.ItemNumber)= ??? IS IN Sheet1!A:A ???  )) " & _
         "ORDER BY MyTable.ItemNumber;"             
cn.Open strConnection
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSql)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Jeff, why did you delete [Automation error when trying INSERT INTO Access DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454094/excel-vba-automation-error-when-trying-insert-into-access-db)?

Comment: OOPS! I thought it was a duplicate of something else I was working on, but I forgot this was something different that I was working on this morning. I accidentally deleted it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right; what you ask is to `join` a table from Access with a table in Excel (ADODB).

Check this link from SO, and see if it's helpful:
[Selecting 2 tables from 2 different databases (ACCESS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access)

I haven't tried to combine Access and Excel before, but my guess is that it will work for Excel as well.

An alternate way (and that will certainly work):

1. Run the query without the `WHERE` clause and store the result in a
   recordset;
2. Store the data from the Excel sheet that you require in a dictionary,
   where the ItemNumber (PK?) is the key;
3. Run through the recordset, and check with the typical dictionary `Exists` function
   if the ItemNumber from each record is available in the dictionary;
4. If the record is availabe, store the
   recordset values in a separate array (or dictionary) that you can
   use for further manipulation, (or perform direct actions if that's what you want to do).

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the link. If I run the query without the `WHERE` clause, the resulting recordset would be over 100,000 records. Would that cause an issue?

Comment: Checking 100000 records will take some time (using the alternative I proposed), although I'm not sure how long. You could test if it's doable; is it something you will do daily? 
Surely try to make the join after all; this would be the fastest. Or can you export the data to Access first and make the query there? That could be an option to consider as well.

Comment: I'm currently trying to `DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet acImport` to put Sheet1 values into a table in Access, then do the query. Thank you for your help!