# Non-static path for IN clause on FROM

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

This is not the `WHERE x IN(1,2,3)` operator, but the **Access-specific** `FROM x IN 'C:\OtherDatabase.mdb'` IN clause.

I have a query which looks up a large number of tables from a separate database file (which frequently changes name and/or path with new versions).

```
SELECT id FROM someTable IN 'C:\OtherDatabase.accdb'
```

works just great. What I'd like to do is offer some flexibility to the user w.r.t. the path and file name of the other database. Consequently, I have another table with a single row which contains the full path. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT id FROM someTable IN DLookup("Path", "tblExternalData")
```

which yields `Syntax error in FROM clause,` then highlights the opening paren in the SQL editor.

I'd rather not individual link a dozen different tables into this database just to query them (examples provided here obviously simplified) The `IN` clause seems perfect for my needs, if I can change it when needed, instead of hard-coding the path into the query!

Comment: This question is confusing, I agree, because this `IN` has no connection whatsoever to the more-frequently-used `WHERE` clause `IN`. I'm trying to retrieve these tables from a completely separate database file. `ID` was a randomly chosen word, the same as `someTable`--it has no relationship to anything at all.

Comment: On the bright side, if this actually gets answered, this will be the one place on the internet people are actually talking about this little-used functionality. I Googled for hours!

Comment: I have tried multiple attempts from multiple angles and none of them have proved successful. I set up the exact test case you're referring to and received the same error. I also tried to use `[Path]` as a Parameter, however when I tried to pass in a file name it could find, it put brackets around it and say it was not a valid name. See if you can get anywhere with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access) method. It seems a lot more plausible in VBA using your DLookup, because we can use the file path as a variable and concatenateit

Answer (score 0):

The only method I've found so far is in VBA:

```
strFileName = DLookup("Path", "tblExternalData")
strSQL = "SELECT id INTO tmpTable FROM someTable IN '" & strFileName & "';"
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

I don't find this a fantastic solution--I don't like merging strings to get executable SQL--but it works for now.