# Ms Access Join tables in separate databases

Tags: sql, database, windows, ms-access, left-join

im trying to create a query that will left join two tables(the tables are in two different databases in my local drive). So far I have come up with this SQL statement but when i run the query it tells me there is an error in the syntax in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT Daily_Report.* INTO AUDIT_TABLE
FROM Daily_Report LEFT JOIN [YTD-Daily_Report] 
IN 'C:\QA_Daily_YTD_Report_Export.accdb'
ON Daily_Report.RecordName = [YTD-Daily_Report].RecordName
WHERE ((([YTD-Daily_Report].RecordName) Is Null));
```

The query outputs a new Table(AUDIT_TABLE) with the records that do not exist in the external table(YTD-Daily_Report) when compared to the local table(Daily_Report).

I have never query tables in separate databases so im pretty lost here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have these tables set as linked tables in access?

Comment: No i don't, im trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: See if this question helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access)

Comment: thanks Zanon, that link also helped to solve the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does the following work for you:

```
SELECT dr.* INTO AUDIT_TABLE
FROM Daily_Report AS dr
LEFT JOIN [;database=C:\QA_Daily_YTD_Report_Export.accdb].[YTD-Daily_Report] AS ytd
   ON dr.RecordName = ytd.RecordName
WHERE ytd.RecordName Is Null
```

Comment: Im sorry, just just checked the data and its consistent with the output that i want it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `;database=`

```
SELECT dr.* INTO AUDIT_TABLE
FROM Daily_Report AS dr
LEFT JOIN [C:\QA_Daily_YTD_Report_Export.accdb].[YTD-Daily_Report] AS ytd
   ON dr.RecordName = ytd.RecordName
WHERE ytd.RecordName Is Null
```