# Identify databases linked to a database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I need to identify all the databases linked to a specific database. Is there an easy way to do this? Just to be clear, if DB1 and DB2 link to a table in DB3, then I'd need to identify DB1 and DB2. I came across [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/210130-identifying-access-databases-tables-linked-other-databases-files), which suggests crawling the network, opening each DB, and checking links, etc. That solution had already occurred to me, but I was looking for something quicker and more direct, if it exists.

Comment: If you know what table(s) that are specifically linked, you may be able to use something like [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123359/selecting-2-tables-from-2-different-databases-access) and use a Public Function with a boolean return to test the result.

Comment: Other then crawling folders and opening each database, I don’t see any other approach. I mean if you have a bunch of word documents sitting on a folder, it not practical or possible to determine who on the network might decide or want to open those word documents. The same goes for an existing database – you have no means to tell who or what program will open or is currently linked to that database. This logic applies to plan Jane text files or to an Access file. You have to go to the “source” that opens (or links) to the given database.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, I get the logic. I guess an example of what I would be looking for would be if an Access DB kept a table that tracked other DBs that were linked to it. That would provide a mechanism to easily determine the linked DBs...something like a doubly linked list. That's just an example, though, and due to lack of any type of feedback close to that I'm assuming this does not exist.